# error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string}) ()’

Tags: c++

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
};

void print (Person* person)
{
    cout << person->name << "is " << person -> age << " years old" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Person person;
    person.name = "Harry";
    person.age = 23;
    
    cout << "Meet " << person.name();
    print (&person);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The error given is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:33:36: error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string}) ()’
     cout << "Meet " << person.name();
```

So the compiler is failing due to line 33. I'm not sure why. I'm using "onlinegdb.com" as my compiler.

Comment: What are you trying to do by adding parentheses after the variable name?

Comment: Remove the empty parentheses after `person.name`.

Comment: My professor wrote the code like that. Not sure why. Seems to be working without the parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: `cout << "Meet " << person.name;` should fix this. VTC as typo.

Comment: Note that if the teacher writes `cout << "Meat " << person.name();` Hope it's another typo. I'd check their bookshelf for a copy of *To Serve Man* just to be sure.

Comment: By the way, you can make `Person` a `struct` and then you don't need the `public` specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the parentheses after person. Because you try to access variable that named "name", however when you put that parenthesses think that it is a function. So that you need to do like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
};

void print (Person* person)
{
    cout << person->name << "is " << person -> age << " years old" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Person person;
    person.name = "Harry";
    person.age = 23;
    
    cout << "Meet " << person.name;
    print (&person);
    
    return 0;
}
```